# MariaDb does not support ANY_VALUE() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb

I have a laravel project which is connected to mysql db, when I change my server, my codes got failed because my new server has a `Mariadb`, when I checked my logs, I have realised that, there is some unsupported function from MariaDb which is `ANY_VALUE()`,

how can I edit my sql according to MariaDb ?

```
select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as price, SUM(price_now) as price_now, 
   ANY_VALUE(price_available) as price_available'),'adult_count')
```

[error log](https://i.hizliresim.com/r5ErAz.png)

Comment: Seems like it's still a work-in-progress based on [this](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10426). Also, the latest comment on that post suggests a possible work-around.

Answer (score 12):

For today, you have solved the problem.  But tomorrow, when you run the same query, you will get a different error.

In older versions of MySQL or MariaDB, you would get "any value" for `price_available` when not `GROUPing BY` it.  That was effectively somewhere between "bad practice" and a "standards violation".  Relatively recently, MariaDB, then later MySQL, switched to "only full group by".  At that time, `ANY_VALUE()` came into existence for MySQL, but apparently MariaDB dropped the ball.

The old workaround, which should be safe for both old and new versions is to use `MIN(price_available)` or some other aggregate function.  (If the column might have `NULL`, the various aggregates might or might not handle `NULL` the way you prefer.)

See also the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved with replacing this:

```
select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as price, SUM(price_now) as price_now, 
    ANY_VALUE(price_available) as price_available'),'adult_count')
```

to

```
select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as price, SUM(price_now) as price_now, 
    price_available as price_available'),'adult_count')
```

Comment: Be careful, this relies on the old permissive group by behavior in MySQL. The code will break on new servers with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY turned on... and this is now on by default... here is a full discussion https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/