# How to write Laravel GroupBy Query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i tried this in laravel, but its not worked.

```
$doctor_daily=ReportDoctorCompanyDailyTestModal::select('test_id','doctor.first_name','testing_types.testing_name',DB::raw('SUM(test_price) as num'))
                                                       ->join('testing_types','report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id','=','testing_types.id')
                                                       ->join('doctor','doctor.id','=','report_doctor_company_daily_test.doctor_id')
                                                       ->groupBy('test_id')
                                                       ->get();
```

How to write this MySQL Query in Laravel 5.7?

```
SELECT
    report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id,
    testing_types.testing_name,
    doctor.first_name,
    doctor.last_name,
    SUM( report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_price ) 
FROM
    testing_types
    INNER JOIN report_doctor_company_daily_test ON testing_types.id = report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id
    INNER JOIN doctor ON report_doctor_company_daily_test.doctor_id = doctor.id 
GROUP BY
    testing_types.id
```

in sql this query working. how can i use it to laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Laravel OrderBy Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507381/how-to-write-laravel-orderby-query)

Comment: Stop duplicating **same questions** with **different titles**

Comment: no. its for different purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this line:

```php
$doctor_daily=TestingType::join('report_doctor_company_daily_test', 'testing_types.id', '=', 'report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id')
                          ->join('doctor', 'report_doctor_company_daily_test.doctor_id', '=','doctor.id')
                          ->groupBy('testing_types.id')
                          ->select('report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id','testing_types.testing_name','doctor.first_name','doctor.last_name',DB::raw('SUM( report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_price )')
                          ->get();
```

Your mysql version is 5.7+, so check this [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list

so check the config/database.php, if your mysql configuration `strict` is true, you need to disabled the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, add modes like this:

```php
'modes' => [
            //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
           ],
```

or you can just use [any_value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) method for the selected columns:

PS: [any_value does not exist on MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10426?focusedCommentId=85142&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-85142)

```php
->selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id),
    ANY_VALUE(testing_types.testing_name),
    ANY_VALUE(doctor.first_name),
    ANY_VALUE(doctor.last_name),
    SUM( report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_price')
```

Comment: 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION medi.ANY_VALUE does not exist....'

Comment: @ChamodWijesena what is the version of your mysql? and do you and `medi` before any_value function?

Comment: 10.1.32-MariaDB

Comment: medi is DB name.

Comment: used code like [$doctor_daily=TestingTypeModel::join('report_doctor_company_daily_test', 'testing_types.id', '=', 'report_doctor_company_daily_test.test_id') .. ]

Comment: It seems your MariaDB not supports `any_value` function, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167995/mariadb-does-not-support-any-value-function), so I think you can use the first solution, disabled the `only_full_group_by`

Comment: putted ever feels to group by  `->groupBy('testing_types.id','doctor.first_name')`

Answer (score 1):

Go to config/database.php and inside 'mysql' change `strict:false` . Now the Group by should work..