# laravel show two tables data grouped as one

Tags: laravel, join

I have two tables named `paths` and `stoppages`, structured as:

**PATHS:**

```
_____________________________
| id | source | destination |
|____|________|_____________|
|  1 |   a    |    b        |
|____|________|_____________|
|  2 |   a    |    c        |
|____|________|_____________|
|  3 |   d    |    e        |
|____|________|_____________|
```

**STOPPAGES:**

```
________________________
| id | path_id | point |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   1     |   p1  |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   1     |   p2  |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   1     |   p3  |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   2     |   p4  |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   2     |   p5  |
|____|_________|_______|
|  1 |   3     |   p1  |
|____|_________|_______|
```

My query to get data from two table is

```
DB::table('paths')->join('stoppages', 'paths.id', '=', 'stoppages.path_id')->get()
```

I want to show them in laravel blade page in one table. Currently my table look like this:

```
________________________________________
| source | destination |   stoppages   |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     b       |       p1      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     b       |       p2      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     b       |       p3      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     c       |       p4      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     c       |       p5      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   d    |     e       |       p1      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
```

But I want to show them in following format?

```
________________________________________
| source | destination |   stoppages   |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     b       |   p1, p2, p3  |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   a    |     c       |     p4, p5    |
|________|_____________|_______________|
|   d    |     e       |       p1      |
|________|_____________|_______________|
```

How to show those data in my desired format?

Comment: I updated my question. please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GROUP_CONCAT function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group

You can use `groupBy` and `group_concat` like this:

```php
DB::table('paths')
  ->join('stoppages', 'paths.id', '=', 'stoppages.path_id')
  ->groupBy('source', 'destination')
  ->select('source', 'destination', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(stoppages separator ", ") AS stoppages'))
  ->get()
```

Comment: adding 'paths.id' in select() gives me the error 
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_graph.paths.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `paths`.`id`, `source`, `destination`, GROUP_CONCAT(stoppages separator ", ") AS stoppages from `paths` inner join `stoppages` on `paths`.`id` = `stoppages`.`path_id` group by `source`, `destination`)` 
can you provide any solution for this?

Comment: @MdYeamin because your mysql version is 5.75+, so it has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, it only allow you to select the column that in group by except the aggregates function. You can use `DB::raw(any_value(paths.id))`,or turn off the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414

Comment: `any_value` also gives error, `DB::raw('min(paths.id) as id'),` saves me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using query builder, use eloquent.

```
Path::with('stoppages')->get();
```

In **Path.php** Model do:

```
public function stoppages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Stoppage::class, 'path_id');
}
```

where Path and Stoppage are models for paths and stoppages table respectively.