# How to group by a single column in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to group my results by a selected Raw Field,

```php
$daily_summaries=DB::table("ticket_transactions")
        ->join('stations', 'stations.id', '=', 'ticket_transactions.station_id')
        ->join('companies' ,'companies.id','=' ,'ticket_transactions.company_id')

        ->where(['company_id'=>$id])
         ->select('ticket_transactions.company_id' , 'companies.name',
                 DB::raw('LEFT(ticket_transactions.date_issued,10) AS day', 'COUNT(ticket_transactions.id) AS tickets_sold',
                 'SUM(fare) AS revenue')
                 )
         ->groupBy('day')
         ->orderBy('day DESC')->get();

        return $daily_summaries;
```

this is my sql when i run it direct.

```sql
select `ticket_transactions`.`company_id`, `companies`.`name`, LEFT(ticket_transactions.date_issued,10) AS day 
from `ticket_transactions` 
inner join `stations` on `stations`.`id` = `ticket_transactions`.`station_id` 
inner join `companies` on `companies`.`id` = `ticket_transactions`.`company_id` 
where (`company_id` = 2) group by `day` order by day DESC
```

Result
[image]

Comment: what is your expected result? GroupBy clause is correct.

Comment: `DB::raw` will only work on the first parameter as far as I know. If you also need the count you might need a second `DB::raw` also your group by might result in arbitrary values of `company_id` and `name` so include them in the group by  to get all of them correctly. In addition if `date_issued` is a date column use `DATE(date_issued)` instead of manipulating it as a string.

Comment: laravel is complaining saying **"Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"**

Comment: you are selecting `company_id` and `name` that not in groupby method, this is not allow with `strict` mode because of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, you can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414)