# LARAVEL Getting 2 of the same columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a table that has animals and another that has the images of the animals (id_image, id_animal).

The problem is that when I do this:

```
$animales = DB::table('animals')
->orderBy('date_found')
->join('images','images.id_animal','animals.id')
->limit(6)
->get();
```

When I do that it returns the same animal for each image that has. That is a problem becuase when I display all the animals it shows the same one multiple times
[image: Example]

What can I do? I tried to use group but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

```
 [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#348 (15) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(5)
      ["id_user"]=>
      NULL
      ["race"]=>
      string(7) "Mestizo"
      ["species"]=>
      string(6) "Canina"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(5) "Macho"
      ["date_of_birth"]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-19"
      ["description"]=>
      string(54) "Un perrito muy bonito y pequeño que busca una familia"
      ["health"]=>
      string(8) "Muy bien"
      ["nickname"]=>
      string(6) "Tudels"
      ["place_found"]=>
      string(8) "Valencia"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "Mediano"
      ["date_found"]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-01"
      ["condition"]=>
      NULL
      ["id_animal"]=>
      int(1)
      ["url"]=>
      string(18) "/img/animals/7.jpg"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#347 (15) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["id_user"]=>
      NULL
      ["race"]=>
      string(7) "Mestizo"
      ["species"]=>
      string(6) "Canina"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(5) "Macho"
      ["date_of_birth"]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-19"
      ["description"]=>
      string(54) "Un perrito muy bonito y pequeño que busca una familia"
      ["health"]=>
      string(8) "Muy bien"
      ["nickname"]=>
      string(6) "Tudels"
      ["place_found"]=>
      string(8) "Valencia"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "Mediano"
      ["date_found"]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-01"
      ["condition"]=>
      NULL
      ["id_animal"]=>
      int(1)
      ["url"]=>
      string(19) "/img/animals/1.jpeg"
    }
```

Comment: is it possible because of you miss `=`?

Comment: I added it and nothing but thanks!

Comment: can I know the relation between the animals and the images? and please show your response using response `json` instead of `var_dump` to make it easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one animals **has many** images. So when you use `join` or `leftjoin`, and if there is one dog has two images, it will become two records which has same dog's columns with different images.

So you can use group by like this:

```php
$animales = DB::table('animals')
              ->orderBy('date_found')
              ->join('images', 'images.id_animal', 'animals.id')
              ->groupBy('animals.id')
              ->limit(6)
              ->get();
```

And if you have set the strict mode in config/database.php, you need to enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.
You can check this [How to write Laravel GroupBy Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414).

Answer (score 2):

Use left join here

```
$animales = DB::table('animals')
->orderBy('date_found')
->leftJoin('images','images.id_animal','animals.id')
->limit(6)
->get();
```

Comment: It stills return the same animal, I edited the question with the return var_dump

Comment: Animals table and images table must contain same rows.