# Eloquent groupBy with MIN condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

I have a large table of items with different price on different dates. To display prices I need a query which returns cheapest item in some time period. Currently I have:

```
$query = Offer::query();
$query->whereBetween('date', [..., ...]);
//other where conditions
$query->selectRaw('*, MIN(price) as lowest_price');
$query->groupBy('item_id');
```

I know I should't be using wildcard selects with group by, so I am stuck. I made a bunch of havingRaw solutions but none have worked.
How can I make this query to get correct results?

EDIT:
I will explain it on hotel example. We have a hotel with rooms and we can give a different price to the room in different time periods. And then query would return all available rooms in specified time period, but this could return same room multiple times if time period is long. And here we can use group by which has to respect where conditions and return cheapest price for every available room (duplicated rooms are not allowed).

Comment: what the error do u face?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Laravel GroupBy Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need the group by. If you want to get the cheapest item (minimum price), just order your result by price and get the first one.

```php
Offer::whereBetween('date', [..., ...])->where(...)->orderBy('price', 'asc')->first();
```

To get all dates with their respective minimum prices, I guess you could do the following:

```
Offer::selectRaw("MIN(price) as min_price, date")->where(...)->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Comment: I thing he needs lowest price for EVERY item in date range.

Comment: Yes, for every item.