# How to get data from SQL in laravel using whereIn and take function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I get data of each value in the array.
I want only 1 result from both values.

```
$userBikes = array('862549040389788','12345');


$data = DB::table('geolocation')
->whereIn('Imei',$userBikes)
->take(1)      
->get();
```

Result:

```
["28.537857", "77.269325", "862549040389788"]
```

but I am expecting this result:

```
["28.537857", "77.269325", "862549040389788"]
["28.537857", "77.269325", "12345"]
```

Comment: Not really clear, what really you want? one of them?

Comment: I want one value from "862549040389788" and one value from "12345" is it clear now?

Comment: but I am getting only value from "862549040389788"

Comment: do u mean one record including two value?

Comment: wait I show you the result what I am getting and what I want

Comment: If there are many results have same value  '862549040389788' and '12345', and if you just want the first row of them, you can just use `groupBy`

Comment: can you show me how ?

Comment: You can try IGP 's answer.

Comment: I am getting error Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'root.geolocation.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `geolocation` where `Imei` in (862549040389788, 12345) group by `Imei`)

Comment: what are the other two columns' names?

Comment: Lat, Lon  and created_at

Comment: I have edited his answer, you can try it.

Comment: If it is still not working, you need to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you want a group by query.

```php
$userBikes = array('862549040389788','12345');

$data = DB::table('geolocation')
->whereIn('Imei', $userBikes)
->groupBy('Imei')
->selectRaw('any_value(id) as id, any_value(Lat) as Lat, any_value(Lng) as Lng, any_value(created_at) as created_at, Imei')
->get();
```

Comment: hey, can I get latest record using this?

Comment: use max instead of any_value ->selectRaw('any_value(lat) as lat, any_value(lon) as lon, max(created_at) as created_at, Imei')

Comment: This only returns one record per (array) value. what if I want to return two records each?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 different queries if you want 1 value for each element in `$userBikes` array.

```
$userBikes = array('862549040389788','12345');
$output = array();


foreach($userBikes as $imei) { 
    $data = DB::table('geolocation')
       ->where('Imei',$imei)
       ->take(1)      
       ->get()->toArray();
    array_push($output, $data)
return $output;
```

Second solution is to remove `take(1)` from query and filtering each value from data object.

Comment: is it the only solution

Comment: @Gaurav Probably yes.

Comment: @Gaurav Yes, it is the only one. Database/Eloquent returns only simple collection/array, not multidimensional.
But This answer is not best. Because this will create as many database requests as it is items in $userBike array. It is better combine Diogos answer and foreach.

Comment: @gaurav `wherein` is replaced with `where`

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the `take(1)` from the query.

Take(1) will limit the results to 1 row.

So it should be:

```
$data = DB::table('geolocation')
->whereIn('Imei',$userBikes)      
->get();
```