# Laravel scope for paid invoices with multiplied columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This should be simple enough, but I can´t get my head around it. I have an invoices table and a payments table. An invoice has many payments and the total payment amount is calculated using the original_amount * exchange_rate. All I need to do is scope out the paid invoices.
Here´s the code:

In Invoice.php

```
public function payments() {

    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
}


public function scopePaid($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('payments', function (Builder $query)) {

        // This is the pseudo code part....
        $query->where('original_amount' * 'exchange_rate', '>=', $invoice->amount_due);

    }
```

I just wish it were that simple, but of course this doesn´t work. I could always create a static function that loops through the invoices checking for their paid status and return a collection of paid invoices, but that is not what a scope is and I am hoping to find something more elegant than that. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` and `havingRaw`:

```php
$query->groupBy('invoice_id')
      ->havingRaw('SUM(original_amount * exchange_rate) >= invoices.amount_due');
```

Comment: Thanks TsaiKoga. But apparently, this is comparing each of the payments to the invoice total, which is not desirable. The comparison should be made between the sum total of the payments for each of the invoices, since an invoice can be paid in one or more installments.

Comment: @E.Barney Updated.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried:  `public function scopePaid($query) {
  return $query->whereHas('payments', function (Builder $query){
   return $query->groupBy('invoice_id')
    ->havingRaw('SUM(original_amount * exchange_rate) >= invoices.amount_due');
  });
 }`
But it didn´t work. I get the following:  <br/> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'lidya.movimientos.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode....

Comment: I´ve also tried:  ` public function scopePaid($query) {
  return $query->groupBy('invoice_id')
   ->havingRaw('SUM(original_amount * exchange_rate) >= invoices.amount_due');
 }`  But also gave me the following error:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice_id' in 'group statement' (SQL: select `id` from `invoices` where `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null group by `invoice_id` having SUM(original_amount * exchange_rate) >= invoices.amount_due)

Comment: @E.Barney this is the mysql `only_full_group_by` problem, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414), you can disable the `only_full_group_by` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TsaiKoga. You truly are a Master!

Just to clarify, the final version is:

```
public function scopePaid1($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('payments', function (Builder $query){
        return $query->groupBy('invoice_id')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(original_amount * exchange_rate) >= invoices.amount_due');
    });
}
```

And it´s important to configure your database following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518382/how-to-write-laravel-groupby-query/60518414#60518414) advice.